# Correct way of throttling kafka consumer messages in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm having a situation where 1 thread is consuming messages from a Kafka topic at a fast rate and putting them into a blocking queue that is then getting consumed in another thread writing bulk inserts into a mongo database collection. I have not seen a lot of answers as this is a common problem, my app is crashing because the message q gets so big and runs out of memory as the mongo db writer thread can't keep up with the message consumption rate.

What is the right way to configure a kafka consumer to pause message consumption for a period of time until the message q gets back to a reasonable size. Can I do a pause or something in the pool loop? I don't think so otherwise the consumer will be flagged as not online, could I close the Kafka consumer every time the message q gets to be too large and then reconnect when its back to a manageable size? I could but that does not seem like a clean solution what I am looking for is to say "hey kafka please pause the sending of messages to my active consumer until I tell you to resume" as this would allow me to pull messages at the speed I can insert them into my data store.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pause and resume method in the kafka api
https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)

If you check the Consumption Flow Control section it states the following:

> Kafka supports dynamic controlling of consumption flows by using pause(Collection) and resume(Collection) to pause the consumption on the specified assigned partitions and resume the consumption on the specified paused partitions respectively in the future poll(long) calls.

Comment: Very nice, all i had to do was look at the javadoc! thanks